# MySQL - Updating 100m+ rows vs truncating and inserting

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, scalability

I've got a table in the following format:

- id: primary key
- foreign_id: foreign key
- code_1: int w index
- code_2: int with index

I have a file that comes in every week with 200m records in the format:

- name (links to the foreign_id above via a separate table lets call it table 2)
- code_1
- code_2

Table 2 has format:
 - id
 - name

In terms of speed / memory usage, would truncating + inserting the 200m rows be better than updating the 200m rows?

Would it perhaps be better to have table 1 and table2 as a single table and update the rows that way?

Initially the reason for splitting out the table required for the dump (table 1) and the id/name table (table 2) is to allow a truncate and insert -> is this the most performant?

Comment: How is your Data structured. Is only part of it changed or do you have to update every row? Does Table2 also contain 200m rows or or is it a considerably smaller number of names?

Comment: please add create table statements and small data sample

Comment: Need the items requested.  Meanwhile, see if there some tips here:  http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: The link is http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table